# No change detection on emit (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, directive, eventemitter

I am trying to get some values to change when I execute an emit from a directive;

**Simplified version:**

HTML:

```
<div testDirective (onTouch)='test()'>
    <p>{{test_value}}</p>
    <a (click)='test()'>get data</a>
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
private test_value: string = '';

test() {
    this.test_value='TEST';
    alert('Value: ' + this.test_value);
}
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({
selector: '[testDirective]',
host: {
        '(document:touchend)': 'touchEnd($event)'
    }
})

export class TestDirective {
    @Output() onTouch: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    touchEnd(e) {
        this.onTouch.emit(null);
    }
}
```

When I press the 'get data' link, I get the data + an alert 'Value: TEST'
When I emit the onTouch, I get no data + an alert 'Value: TEST'

Anyone who knows what the difference between these two methods is and why Angular does not detect this change in value when emitting, but does when clicking?

Answer (score 0):

I think @Output is only between parent and child. You can use a subject to communicate between directive and its host.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDir]'
})
export class MyDir {
  @Input() myDir;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) onClick() {
    this.myDir.next(true);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>isClicked: {{obs | async}}</h2>
      <div [myDir]="subject">Click me</div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  subject = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  obs = this.subject.asObservable();

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Output should work on a directive since at the moment it's called, it's an instance of the Component used. It does execute the code and changes the data, just doesn't trigger change detection..

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding a zone.run to my change:

```
zone.run(() => this.test_value = 'TEST');
```